# How to prevent fixed image from scrolling down?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an image in the top right corner of my page. It is a fixed element, so whenever I zoom in or out it stays in the top right corner of the browser as intended. The thing that happens which I don't intend, is that when scrolling down the page, the image follows. I want it to constantly be in the page's top right corner when zooming in/out, but to stay static when I scroll down so it remains on the top of the page with all other content which is positioned there. Here is the code for the element:

```
<div id="abox" class="Mbox"><a href="#" style="font-family:arial;font-size:120%;text-decoration:none;" title="title">Some text</a></div>

<div id="abox" class="Cbox"><a href="#" style="font-family:arial;fontsize:120%;
text-decoration:none;" title="title">Text</a>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;>
<img class="imagebox" src="image.png" alt="alt" title="title">
<div id="textbox" style="margin-right:450px;">Some text here.</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
#abox {
position:relative;
}


.Mbox {
left:20px;
bottom:335px;
}


.Cbox {
left:45px;
bottom:505px;
}


#longbox {
width:50000px;
height:50px;
position:relative;
bottom:8px;
right:8px;
}



.imagebox {
width:45px;
height:27px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

I tried using absolute, but when using right:0px, no matter how much I zoom out I can't find the image - it disappears. Instead I tried shifting it from the left (e.g: left:900px), but that obviously didn't keep in moving to the right whenever I zoomed out. When using float:right; my image also disappears. These may be irrelevant anyway, but worth mentioning.

Ultimately, I want the image to be interactive in the sense it continues to shift to the right to stay in the top-right corner as I zoom out(/in), but when scrolling down I do not want it to follow.

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I have added more of the HTML and CSS, and tried the absolute method only for the image to remain disappeared. When I go back to `position:fixed;right:0px;top:10px;` for the embedded CSS of the image, I go back to the original issue with it staying in the corner as intended but still following my scroll.

Comment: what is the `.Langbox` for?

Comment: If possible please add the whole html and css part.

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: @MoshFeu Please see updated code with same issue.

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Please see updated code with same issue.

Comment: @GvM Please see updated code with same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i used position absolute I dont find any changes. And I set a extra div class test. with a height.. No you can test it. zooming in and out. the abc div you will find in same place

```css
.abc{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.test {
  height: 200vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
 <img class="box" src="a src" alt="an alt" title="a title">
</div>
   <div class="test">
   </div>
```

Comment: @H3ll0 why you set longbox width 5000px and in your body style you set overflow-x-hidden. so that's why you dont see the img which you set on the right side of the longbox div. And you used same ID abox for to div

Comment: @H3ll0 what actually you want to make with longbox??

Comment: It is simply a banner at the top of the page. Elements are placed on this banner using position:relative, but the image in discussion here is not using relative.

Comment: @H3ll0 I don't know why the width of longbox is 5000px but. if you want to see the right image in your current code just change the style on body overflow:auto;  . I'm also update my code. But I changes lots. If you have any question about my updated answer ask me.

Comment: Image problem seems good, but removing 50000px from longbox and making its width auto does not cause it to fill the full screen width. The left and right sides have gaps. The problem was with longbox, not overflow. I have no brought its width back to 50000px (no reason for that number) and kept overflow-x hidden. The I change I made to resolve this was to remove the image from longbox's div. This way it's independent, and won't be at the end of the 50000px box. And of course, using position:absolute prevents the image from scrolling down. Thank you for your contribution, issue resolved.

Comment: @H3ll0 the left right gaps are came from body. Here is a fiddle example [https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/L3zkyj5a/1/ ] without using any position and images responsive. Maybe this fiddle help you also . THanks :)

Comment: So how would you get rid of those gaps if I were to keep the width as auto?

Comment: Yes, the ones on the left and right side of the screen for the banner we just discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:-

```css
   body  {
        background-image: url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
      
    }
```

```html
 <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>If you do not see any scrollbars, try to resize the browser window.</p>
```

or

```css
 body  {
        background-image: url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        position:fixed;
        top:10px;
        right:0px;
    }
```

```html
 <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
    <p>If you do not see any scrollbars, try to resize the browser window.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use position: absolute

Try doing what you did before with absolute but specify a width and height of the div

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:0px;width:100px;height:100px">
    <img class="box" src="a src" alt="an alt" title="a title">
</div>
```

hopefully that should work

Edit: Looking at the new code, you should just make #longbox width:100% then the image will show up. Currently the image is at the right of #longbox but that's 50000px long so it doesn't fit on the screen